# Circles in pygame vibrating instead of moving

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code. Currently this program just has one blob (circle) which is supposed to move around and bounce along the walls of the window. Instead of the blob moving, they just vibrate around the position they are in. I can't understand what the problem is.

```
import pygame   
import random
from settings import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dt = 0 

running = True

class Blob:
    def __init__(self, radius, position, color):
        self.radius = radius
        self.position = pygame.Vector2(position)
        self.velocity = pygame.Vector2(random.randint(-5, 5), random.randint(-5, 5)) 
        self.color = color

    def update(self, dt):
        self.position += self.velocity * dt

        if self.position.x < 0 or self.position.x > dimensions[0]:
            self.velocity.x *= -1

        if self.position.y < 0 or self.position.y > dimensions[1]:
            self.velocity.y *= -1

    def show(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, self.position, self.radius)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(background)

    blob = Blob(40, initial_position, blobcolor)
    blob.update(dt)
    blob.show(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000

pygame.quit()
```

I tried debugging by printing out the position and velocity values, and it seems fine. PS - I am new to programming, sorry if this question is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the `Blob` object in the application loop, it means that a new object is created at a new position in each frame. You must create the `Blob` object once before the application loop and not in the loop.

```py
blob = Blob(40, initial_position, blobcolor)      # <-- INSERT

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(background)

    # blob = Blob(40, initial_position, blobcolor)  <-- DELETE
    blob.update(dt)
    blob.show(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000
```